# Is there a way to see if a task already has a continuation?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Is there a way to find out if a task already has a continuation? I would like to add a continuation to an existing task, only if the task does not yet have a continuation, like this:

```
void RequestUpdate()
{
    if (_updateTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        _updateTask = TakeASnapshotOfTheCurrentStateAndUpdateAsync();
    }
    else 
    {
        if (_updateTask.HasNoContinuation){ // how do I check for this?
            _updateTask.ContinueWith(() => RequestUpdate())
        }
    }
}
```

Or is there a better way to write this kind of logic?

Comment: Create a new task that `await`s `_updateTask` and calls `RequestUpdate` -- and ensure you only do that once by keeping track of that task? Continuations don't seem like the right tool here.

Comment: That has a nasty race condition - `_updateTask.IsCompleted` could become `true` immediately after you check it, before the `else` is executed. Also, after you use `ContinueWith()` you would need to assign a task variable to the return value, e.g. `_updateTask = _updateTask.ContinueWith(() => RequestUpdate())`

Comment: Is this just a very convoluted way to continuously call `TakeASnapshotOfTheCurrentStateAndUpdateAsync` in a tight loop?

Comment: @Fildor No, my intention is that a RequestUpdate should be called again at the end of TakeASnapshotOfTheCurrentStateAndUpdateAsync if RequestUpdate is called while the task is running. Otherwise, TakeASnapshotOfTheCurrentStateAndUpdateAsync should just terminate without any follow-up.

Comment: Then: How about something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/o5iC4M ?

Answer (score 7):

Technically, we can break into [private affairs](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,27c5b7fbe5caaa18) of the `Task` class with a help of *reflection* and implement something like this:

```
using System.Reflection;

...

private static bool HasContinuation(Task task) {
  if (task is null)
    return false;

  var result = typeof(Task)
    .GetField("m_continuationObject", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
   ?.GetValue(task);

  return result is not null && result?.GetType() != typeof(object);
}
```

However, the code above is nothing but a quick (and *dirty*) patch; there's no guarantee that future versions of .net will use `m_continuationObject` field.